# AngularJS ng-style escaping illegal characters in variables

Tags: javascript, css, json, angularjs

The numbers are not being picked up presumably because x-offset is not being escaped correctly. What is the right way of putting the values from the controller into ng-style?

The data looks something like this:

```
{
    "item": {
        "x-offset": 4,
        "y-offset": 5
    }
}
```

and the html:

```
<div ng-style="{backgroundPosition: -item['x-offset']+'px' -item['y-offset']+'px'}"></div>
```

Comment: In order to encourage answers, maybe open a JSFiddle showing this code!

Comment: Is `item` part of the scope?

Comment: item is part of the scope. It was working correctly while it was just bound to style="background-position={{-item['-x-offset']}}px... but now that I've switched to ng-style, it's not picking up that specific one. I have another attribute after it that works correctly: width:item.width+'px' so the issue is not with the contents of item, but with the way I'm putting it into ng-style.

Comment: Who ever sent you that data needs a spanking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the rest of the css string in quotes and concatenate it properly:

```
<div ng-style="{backgroundPosition: '-' + item['x-offset']+'px -' + item['y-offset']+'px'}"></div>
```

Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQpgY/2/